# What behavior results from both ip dhcp pool and ip helper-address?

Tags: cisco, dhcp

If a device has a dhcp pool defined:

```
ip dhcp pool DATA
  network 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0
  default-router 192.0.2.1
  domain-name test.net
```

But it also has a DHCP helper setup on the interface:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
  ip address 192.0.2.1 255.255.255.0
  ip helper-address 198.51.100.10
```

Then what is the result? Is the DHCP addresses given from the helper? or from the local pool?

Comment: I would have to lab this out to be sure, but I believe you will get an offer from both the local pool and from the DHCP server 198.51.100.10 (if it exists).  If I get a chance later, I will try to run this in my lab to confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the DHCP addresses given from the helper? or from the local pool?

**You would get two possible DHCPOffer's from the device's internal DHCP pool and the DHCP server defined by the helper-address, but it's up to the client to decide which DHCPOffer to accept and to then unicast a DHCPRequest to the DHCP server of choice.**

Often clients choose the DHCP server with the fastest DHCPOffer.  Unless your device's CPU is bogged down, I would expect typical clients to select the DHCP pool more often than not.  You'd expect a little less latency in a L2 operation vs L3 which is required to get to the DHCP server via the helper-address.

Comment: Given there isn't anything wrong with the DHCP packet, it always comes down to the fastest response.